# How to select background views in a storyboard or xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, interface-builder, uistoryboard

If I select a view with my mouse in a storyboard or xib, Xcode will select the front most view. I know that I can select the other views in the document outline, but if I want to grab a background view to move it with my mouse, the front most view gets selected again when I click in the storyboard.

I think there is a way to cycle through the views and select the ones in the back by holding down on some keys, but I can't find what it is. Does anyone know?

I'm using Xcode 4.6. I know that I can also move background views using the size inspector, but I'm looking for a way to position them with my mouse.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One way is to use the jump bar at the top of the editor. It's the control that shows the path of objects leading to the current selection.

Another way is to press **control+shift and left click** (or **shift right click**) an item. That shows you all of the objects under the mouse in a menu, and allows you to disambiguate the one you meant to select.

Comment: Great thanks! It seems though that the command key is not necessary (although it still works if I press it, it also works if I don't press it).

Answer (score 7):

The good news: Place your mouse on the overlapped images, press and hold shift and right click the mouse. You should see the list of objects, select your object in the back. You can resize as you wish.

The bad news: you can only use the cursor arrows if you want to move it!

Comment: Thanks, even if I can't move it with my mouse, using the keyboard is a good tip.

Answer (score 1):

Select the view from the menu on the left of interface builder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's the document outline, and as I wrote in my question, I already know how to do that. It doesn't help me though because when I try to grab the view with my mouse to move it or resize it, the front most view gets selected again.