# Xcode 9 shows menu on Ctrl+drag

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

This must be very simple, but Xcode is really frustrating me. On literally my very first iOS app ever:

1. Create new project, using Single View App template.
2. Open `main.storyboard` and `ViewController.swift` side by side.
3. Drop a button and position it.
4. Now, to create the outlet to respond to my button click, I understand that I'm supposed to hold down control while dragging the button to the editor. This works approximately one time in ten. Instead, any attempt to click or control-click on the button, Xcode throws up this silly menu:
   [image: Menu on control-click]

For the life of me, I don't understand why this happens and I don't understand why this menu pops up and how to avoid it, but it means I can't use the control-drag feature at all.

I should add that I'm using a 2017 Macbook Pro with a touch bar and that I don't have problems dragging and dropping in any other app, nor in Xcode in any other circumstance.

I can see that it wants me to select either the control or one of its parents, but how do I drag when the menu pops up?

Comment: Try right-click+dragging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like sanjaykmwt has said. That menu only shows up if you press the shift button while control-dragging.

The menu is for you select views that are underneath (covered by) other views. Sometimes you might have trouble selecting certain views if they are under other views, right? That's when you shift+control+click and the menu will show you all the views that are on top of each other. In your screenshot, the button is onto of the `UIView` and the `UIView` is on top of the `UIViewController`.

Another way to do control-drag is to do a right-click drag. If you haven't noticed already, control+click is equal to a right-click.

You can also try connecting the outlet using the connections inspector:

[image]

Drag the circle next to "New Referencing Outlet" into the assistant editor *normally*.

Comment: I'm not holding Shift and the key is definitely not stuck, so I don't understand why this is happening. As for right-click dragging: dragging with a single-finger click is awkward enough on Mac's touch pad - two-finger dragging sounds absolutely horrid. The connections inspector looks like the workaround of choice here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happens when we hold `ctrl + shift` and then drag the mouse.
So think in that way either you are accidentally pressing both the keys or some functionality like sticky keys in windows doing this.

I think this will help out you to think about the issue in a much better way.

Comment: Nope, I'm not holding Shift as well. I don't know of something like sticky keys on MacOS, but then again, I would expect to by typing in uppercase if that was the case.

Comment: you need some assistance bro.
see this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142515/how-to-select-background-views-in-a-storyboard-or-xib)

Comment: Yeah, that's the opposite of my problem. I know how to select the background view, but couldn't drag. The connections inspector suggested by sweeper is going to work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class in the inspector on which controller you work, not the standard UIViewController, UITableViewController, etc.
Then drag and drop outlet/actions/outlet collections will work
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ9fQ.png)